# Delete between ")" and string

Tags: python

I want to delete the text between a bracket and a string, but i keep getting this error: `sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 8`

```
import re

s = 'TEXT1 ) something something TEXT2'
test= re.sub(r'(?<=^)\b).*(?=\bTEXT2)',' ',s)
print(test)
```

I want to keep the identifiers so my output looks like this:

```
"TEXT1 ) TEXT2"
```

Comment: `(?<=^)` is equivalent to `^`.

Comment: Is `TEXT2` the last word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that you aren't escaping the `)` which leads to the error. You can do almost what you are doing with the back ref and forward ref:

```
import re
s = 'TEXT1 ) something something TEXT2'
test= re.sub(r'(?<=\)).*(?=\bTEXT2)',' ',s)
print(test)
```

**result:**

```
TEXT1 ) TEXT2
```

It doesn't matter what the initial text is:

```
s = 'any text whatsoever!! ) something something TEXT2'
re.sub(r'(?<=\)).*(?=\bTEXT2)',' ',s)
# any text whatsoever!! ) TEXT2
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need.

```
import re

s = 'TEXT1 ) something something TEXT2'
#test= re.sub(r'(^\w+\s*\))(.*?)(?=\bTEXT2)', r'\1 ',s)
test= re.sub(r'(\)).*(?=\bTEXT2)',r'\1 ',s)
print(test)
```

**Output:**

```
TEXT1 ) TEXT2
```

- Note: In your regex pattern you need to escape the bracket - `\)` (Error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 8)

Comment: This seems break with strings like `s = 'TEXT1? ) something something TEXT2'`

Comment: It works though if it was like this ") something something TEXT2" it didn't work because the bracket was the first character.

Comment: Oh ok..i misunderstood. Thought Text1 is also an identifier. `test= re.sub(r'(\)).*(?=\bTEXT2)',r'\1 ',s)`